# Embeded PSB in PSD file for faster editing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have worked with many mockup files in Photoshop, but I have yet to understand how PSB files are linked into a PSD.

[image: PSB link in PSD]

How do I create this link which I can link a PSB which would make editing a bit faster?

Comment: Are you more concerned with how to make a psb file or why people use linked smart objects (PSB file)? Are you also trying to embed a smart object instead of having it linked?

Comment: It's easy to turn anything into a smart object (psb file), select the Layer -> Convert to Smart Object.

Comment: @AndrewH I was first concerned with how to make a psb file and now I know it was smart objects. That was the magic button!! Thank you for the tip, helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**How to make a PSB file / Smart Object inside a PSD**

Right click on the layer, select "Convert to Smart Object". This will open a new file in Photoshop. This new file is a linked psb file and saved locally on your computer. If you want to open this file again, click on the thumbnail with this icon.

[image: Smart Object Icon]

**How to save any file as a PSB / Large Photoshop Document**

Go to File -> Save As and change the format to "Large Document Format"

**Difference between a PSD and Large Document Format (PSB)**

For files larger than 2 GB that you want to save with Photoshop editing capabilities, save in Large Document Format (PSB).